# Query to find the Columns without data from a table Dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by

I wrote a Query to find the Columns without data from a table Dynamically.,
But its giving output only with rownum=1, which is also incorrect.,

```
WITH x AS (SELECT column_name FROM all_tab_cols 
WHERE OWNER='HR' AND table_name='EMPLOYEES' AND ROWNUM=1)     
SELECT X.column_name,count(X.column_name)
FROM EMPLOYEES,X
/*CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT count(1) FROM all_tab_cols 
WHERE OWNER='HR' AND table_name='EMPLOYEES')*/
group by X.column_name;

COLUMN_NAME                    COUNT(X.COLUMN_NAME)   
------------------------------ ---------------------- 
EMPLOYEE_ID                    20
```

when I'm trying to use level to make it dynamic it fails.,

```
WITH x AS (SELECT column_name FROM all_tab_cols 
WHERE OWNER='HR' AND table_name='EMPLOYEES' AND ROWNUM=level)     
SELECT X.column_name,count(X.column_name)
FROM EMPLOYEES,X
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT count(1) FROM all_tab_cols 
WHERE OWNER='HR' AND table_name='EMPLOYEES')
group by X.column_name;
```

> Error at Command Line:14 Column:5
>       Error report:
>       SQL Error: ORA-01788: CONNECT BY clause required in this query block
>       01788. 00000 -  "CONNECT BY clause required in this query block"

Cud u correct the query for achieving the same?

Answer (score 0):

Your query has some issues:

- subquery in `with` clause does not *see* `level` from other subquery,
- you cannot use `where rownum = 2`, you have to make alias for this column and select it from inner query, but this part is not needed in your case,
- hierarchical suqbquery is not needed at all if you want to check all columns.

Corrected query would be:

```
with x as (
  select column_name from all_tab_cols 
    where owner='HR' and table_name='EMPLOYEES')
select x.column_name, count(x.column_name) as cnt
  from x, employees group by x.column_name;
```

... but it always shows number of ALL rows in `employees` for each column. So if you want to find columns where 
not all data is filled, you need dynamic solution. You can add something like `...where ||'r.column_name' is null` in variable `v_sql`:

```
declare
  v_sql varchar2(1000);
  v_num number;
begin
  for r in (select column_name from all_tab_cols 
            where owner='HR' and table_name='EMPLOYEES'
            order by column_id)
  loop
    v_sql := 'select count('||r.column_name||') from employees';
    execute immediate v_sql into v_num;
    dbms_output.put_line(rpad(r.column_name,30)||' '||v_num);
  end loop;
end;
```

Example data and output:

```
create table employees (id number(3), name varchar2(10), hire_date date);
insert into employees values (1, 'John', trunc(sysdate));
insert into employees values (2, 'Paul', trunc(sysdate));
insert into employees values (3, 'Mark', trunc(sysdate)-1);
insert into employees values (4, 'Anna', null);

ID                             4
NAME                           4
HIRE_DATE                      3
```